# Is there a way to check if a user is signed in with Twitter?

Tags: ios, api, twitter, parse-platform

I am following this tutorial

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#twitterusers/iOS

For this app, I'm doing a sign in with Twitter deal. There's one problem. If a user is not signed into twitter (they didn't sign in from settings), nothing is displayed when this code runs:

```
[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
        return;
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in with Twitter!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in with Twitter!");
    }    
}];
```

I am wondering if there is a way to check if a user is signed in from settings so I can set up a message saying they should sign in from settings. Does anyone know a way to check this?

Comment: try this `if ([PFUser currentUser] && [PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]])
        NSLog(@"Already login with twitter"); else NSLog(@"Not login with twitter");` working fine for me

Comment: @MohitPopat I'm talking about if you are not logged into Twitter on the device at all, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

I am using TwitterKit and installed it with cocoapod
Twitterkit has sessionstore which stores session for the logged in users.

```
if TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session() != nil {
            print("user signed in with twitter ..")
}
```

For logout from twitter

```
func logoutTwitter() {
        let store = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore
        if let userID = store.session()?.userID {
            store.logOutUserID(userID)
        }
}
```

This is how to get information about logged in user

```
func getTwitterUserInformation() {
    let store = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore
    if let userID = store.session()?.userID {

        let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
        client.loadUser(withID: userID) { (user, error) in
            print(user?.name)
            print(user?.screenName)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Its successfully logout from twitter. But when I again login it then it will directly show me the Authorize app instead of username and password text filed. Any idea how can I show username and password text filed while logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the service is available and if not then do whatever. And this is checking that there is an account in Settings|Twitter

This is in Swift but you get the idea

```
import Social

if !SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter){
        println("No Account Setup")
    } else {
        println("Yes Account Setup")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
let twitterSession = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()
```

*Returns*

No logged in user: nil

Logged in user: TWTRSession