# Twitter Authenticate Issue from iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, twitter

I am facing one issue in Twitter sharing, i am allowing user to tweet from my Application via Authenticating from Twitter App. once I user Authenticate app to tweet it allows user but and later on if user Logout from twitter app and from my iOS app again tap on button for tweet it also opens tweet composer.

I have also check for user login in app or not below is code

```
if TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.hasLoggedInUsers() {
    let composer = TWTRComposer()
    composer.setText("text")
    composer.setURL(url)

    // Called from a UIViewController

    composer.show(from: self) { result in
        if result == TWTRComposerResult.cancelled {
            print("Tweet composition cancelled")
        } else {
            print("Sending tweet!")
        }
    }
}
```

even if user logged out from app `hasLoggedInUsers()` returns true.

Anyone have any idea how this session is manage or how we have to check if user login in Twitter app or not.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check out here how to logout properly from twitter.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51417265/7445439

Comment: private func logOutSessionStoreTwitter() {
         let store = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore
         
         if let userID = store.session()?.userID {
             store.logOutUserID(userID)
         }
     }

Comment: @HafizShoaibAwan even if i logout from Twitter app and come to my app and share tweet this line returns me session .   let twitterSession = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()  how twitter manages user session?